# disable mongo db connection messages while exporting query results to the csv

Tags: mongodb

how to prevent the mongo db connection messages while exporting query results  to the csv?
used --quiet command but its not working when I connect to remote DB?

C:\test>mongo  test.js > test.csv

MongoDB shell version v5.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://xxx.x.xx.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("5858-78a6-4e23-83d3-320e7883fd7b") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.6

Comment: you could use grep to ignore connection message `mongo test.js | grep -v "MongoDB shell" > test.csv`

Comment: how to run the same command in windows?